# Assign a process Instance in Camunda

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

i am using camunda REST i would like to know whats the best way to work with task / process Instance assignments. There is a REST call that assigns a single task to a user but after submitting the task the assignment is lost.

My goal is to assign the complete process Instance to a person. But i am not sure if this rly makes sense or not and if yes then how ?
If this is not possible or doesnt make sense, how would you handle the fact that after submitting a task the assignment is lost ? Would you reassign every time the next task?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It could totally make sense to assign all user tasks of a process to a specific user or group.
You could model this in the bpmn by setting the assignee to a variable (`${assignee}`) and then just set this variable once on the process instance. All tasks then are automatically assigned to the user named in the variable.